# Looking for alternative of ArcGIS REST API Connector Plugin in QGIS 3

Tags: qgis-3, qgis-plugins, import, esri-geodatabase

I am trying to open feature services from Enterprise Geodatabase to QGIS. I've downloaded the ArcGIS API Connector Plugin, but it seems to only work with QGIS version 2.0 - 2.9. I am running QGIS version 3.32.0. Do you have any suggestions on how I can resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can connect directly to your ArcGIS REST services from QGIS, you don't need a plugin.

From the [documentation](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/managing_data_source/opening_data.html?highlight=arcgis#using-arcgis-rest-servers):

> ArcGIS REST Servers can be added via the ArcGIS REST
> Server tab of the Data Source Manager dialog or the contextual menu of the ArcGIS REST Servers entry in the Browser panel.

[image]